# Laravel - Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm migrating an application to another server and it returns me this error:

```
Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
```

I thin this is about charset or collection but in mysql workbench it tells me that my database settings is this:

```
default collaction: utf8_general_ci
default charset: utf8
```

I put this in my config file, clean cache but the error continuous.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Also check "table" settings... each table has its own charset / collation settings. The database's default values are only used when you create new table and not specify charset/collation.

Comment: @Kyslik the tables are with utf8_unicode_ci . I change the collation to this but don't work.

Comment: Specify exact PHP version and MySQL version.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you fix it?

PHP 7.0.20 & MySQL 8.0.11. utf8mb4 & utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: If you using MySQL 8+ try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051440/server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-set-mysql-charset-to-utf8-w-o)