# mysql_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP 5.6.40 and MySQL 5.7 but when I want to connect remote database(MySQL 8), occur a problem.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client.

Although I tried a lot of things like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep) but nothing has changed.

My Connection Code

```
$connect = mysql_connect("XXX:25060","XXX","XXX") or die ();
mysql_select_db("defaultdb", $connect) or die ( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: I hope you use PDO or myqli extensions instead of mysql because it is deprecated in later version of PHP. Despite i really eager to see your connection code, so please edit your question by posting it.

Comment: I  am not supposed to make any changes, I have to use mysql. I know mysql is deprecated but my server environment still work with mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client" Set MySQL charset to utf8 w/o /etc/my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051440/server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-set-mysql-charset-to-utf8-w-o)

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses different character set (utf8mb4), so you must change configuration of MySQL.

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

I hope you know that you should not use `mysql_` functions.