# How to see why mysql_connect fails?

Tags: php, mysql

I've installed Linux (Mint) & LAMP but

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')
```

fails no matter what I try.

I spend at least 6 hours trying to fix it.

```
phpinfo()
```

is working

```
sudo mysql -u user -p
```

works

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6
```

What else can I try?
How do I debug? I've been googling for hours.
The only non-standard thing is that I've installed php 5.6, since I need it, "php -v" returns:

```
PHP 5.6.40-30+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologie
```

Comment: Fails? What's the error? How does it fail? Could start with what is returned by `mysql_connect `. We assume `false`?

Comment: `php -v` in the command line is not necessarily the PHP on the webserver. What version of PHP is shown in `phpinfo()` in the browser?

Comment: PHP5.6 is end-of-life since 2019, and the `mysql_*()` functions are removed from 7. Upgrade both your PHP version and your workflow. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: In 2020 do not even start with mysql_*() functions. If you have to support some legacy application, then it's fine, otherwise just forget about it.

Comment: It fails because it is very, very old. Just like granny trying to juggle glasses of hot milk

Comment: I understand PHP 5 is old. I had a Moodle server that worked on 5.6 and the HDD stopped working and I am only left with database dumps. I have to restore the whole system to get data from the database (quizzes, grades, etc,...). After I get my data back, I will update the system to PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY need to use `mysql_connect` and that old PHP:

The first example at https://www.php.net/mysql_connect shows how you can see the error... I am not sure where you spent those 6 hrs :)

```php
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); // MAGIC LINE
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

My suggestion, as well as everyone else, is (as the comments under your question suggest): UPGRADE to PHP7.4 and then use the appropriate PDO/Mysqli connectors

Comment: Thanks. I got "Could not connect: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051440/server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-set-mysql-charset-to-utf8-w-o

Comment: @JakeB. You're possibly connecting to a modern MySQL server. The problem with the legacy MySQL extension was that it wasn't being properly maintained so it just lacks basic features like proper Unicode support and, of course, it's wasn't being updated to include newer MySQL features.

Comment: Yep. It will be way easier if he just upgrades his whole setup.